# how would I create an animation in android, specifically one that looks like a speedometer?

Tags: android, image, animation

I am creating an app that is a speedometer, but right now, it looks very bland. what I want to do, is make it look like a speedometer in a modern car. one that would have the number, and then the needle pointing to the number as well. specifically what I am looking for is something that looks like this: http://static.howstuffworks.com/gif/vehicle-pictures/2009/honda/fit/5802-062-speedometer-tachometer-480.jpg
how would I go about doing that i.e creating the speedometer and moving the needle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess Open GL  is the way to go for u

Comment: how do I use OpenGL, I have tried, but I have never been able to fully understand how it works

Comment: A good starting point for you then would be http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily OpenGL.. 
It can be done with quite good performance results just by extending some view and writing your own onDraw method.. 
Especially if scale is fixed and just pointer is moving.. Cheers